# JPA merge after delete query fails

Tags: java, sql, jpa, h2

please analize the following two codes and tell me why the first one fails with primary key violation when doing commit, and the second one does't.

Code which fails at commit:

```
try{

        Query q = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Puntaje");
        q.executeUpdate();
        //em.getTransaction().commit();

        //em.getTransaction().begin();
        Iterator it = l.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            DataPuntaje dp = (DataPuntaje)it.next();
            Cliente c = new Cliente(dp.getCliente());
            Puntaje p = new Puntaje(dp.getPuntaje(),c);
            c.agregarPuntaje(p);

            em.merge(c);

        }


   System.out.println("test1");
        em.getTransaction().commit();
   System.out.println("test2");
    }
```

Code which works fine:

```
try{

        Query q = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Puntaje");
        q.executeUpdate();
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Iterator it = l.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            DataPuntaje dp = (DataPuntaje)it.next();
            Cliente c = new Cliente(dp.getCliente());
            Puntaje p = new Puntaje(dp.getPuntaje(),c);
            c.agregarPuntaje(p);

            em.merge(c);

        }


   System.out.println("test1");
        em.getTransaction().commit();
   System.out.println("test2");
    }
```

The only difference is that the first one does not commit the delete query, but instead commit it all together at the end.
Cliente and Puntaje is a 1:N bidirectional relation with cascade = ALL.
And all the inserted instances of Cliente have the same ID, but merge should be smart enough to update instead of insert after the first one is persisted, but that seems to fail at the first example and i cant find any explanation.
Also im using H2 embedded database.

Also i would like to add, the first code works FINE if there is an already inserted Cliente value, this fails when the table is actually empty and so delete actually is doing nothing.

This is the error im getting:

```
Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_5 ON PUBLIC.CLIENTE(NICK)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO CLIENTE (NICK) VALUES (?) [23505-169]
Error Code: 23505
Call: INSERT INTO CLIENTE (NICK) VALUES (?)
        bind => [cbaldes]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Clases.Cliente@21cd5b08)
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_5 ON PUBLIC.CLIENTE(NICK)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO CLIENTE (NICK) VALUES (?) [23505-169]
Error Code: 23505
Call: INSERT INTO CLIENTE (NICK) VALUES (?)
        bind => [cbaldes]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Clases.Cliente@21cd5b08
```

)

These are the tables:

```
@Entity
public class Puntaje implements Comparable, Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private int total;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="NICK")
    private Cliente cliente;


@Entity
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String nick;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="cliente")
    private List<Puntaje> puntajes;
```

Comment: Are you receiving a primary key violation for 'Cliente' or 'Puntaje'? Could you post your stacktrace?

Comment: Yup, primary key exception, seems like it is not smart enough to only insert ONCE and then update all the rest, it tries to insert on every merge, which is weird since delete does nothing, it just fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform operations on the object, all the operations are recorded in the cache ONLY. **JPA will prepare an internal list of all objects to be inserted, updated and deleted.** Which will be flushed together when `flush` or `commit`is called.

Now take your first example. You deleted all `Puntaje`, which adds all `Puntaje` in the `deleted` list. Now when you call `merge`, i**ts indeed smart enough** and it figured out that it should be inserted and not updated and added in the `insert` list. When you call commit, it tries to insert the objects from the insert list first and as you can expect, **it will fail as old objects are not yet deleted.**

Only difference in your second example is that, by force, you are deleting the objects first before insertion and hence it's not failing.

I am sure, it will not fail even if your use `flush` in place of `commit`.

Hope this helps you understand the reasoning behind the failure.

Comment: It fails with flush as well!

Comment: Also, the tuples i was trying to insert had all the same ID (on the Cliente side) but new Puntaje, so even after all the old ones are deleted, only the first merge is an insert and the rest is an update, why isn't JPA smart enough then to do exactly the same without commiting the delete operation? 
I forgot to mention, this happens when the table is totally empty (so delete actually does nothing)

Comment: @user1777914 Did you put flush after delete? Can you do a select after delete to make sure it really flushed?

Comment: Yes i did, a select would return no resulsts since the table was empty on the first place.

Comment: @user1777914: I missed this part. Its because you are using query `DELETE FROM Puntaje` the query to delete all `Puntaje`. I explained the concept when you delete certain objects. I am thinking JPA does something similar but little more for this kind of query operations.  Also I believe this is causing `flush` not working as delete was not around some specific object but its a generic query which comes into effect at `commit` as well.

Comment: @user1777914: I think if you load your existing objects, delete them if found with flush, it should work.

Comment: But how come delete actually does nothing at all, since the table was empty at the first place. If the table Cliente had already the value im trying to insert then merge works fine even after deleting all without commit.

Comment: @yes, it will work fine as in that case its only `update` on `insert`. I am bit confused now. Is Cliente empty or `Pujante` empty? I believe your issue is originating from because of Pujante. Do you have unique key contraint on pujante Id column in Cliente? Please share your table structure with constraint definitions.

Comment: Im sorry, Cliente is empty and also Puntaje, Puntaje has an auto generated key:@Id
              @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
              private Long id;

Edit: Added the tables.
I have tried deleting the Puntaje table using JPA remove operation and it works in both codes, yet im curious about the first code it should work.

Comment: @user1777914: That is what I tried to mention you. `removing` the object works as you are marking specific object instance to be deleted.  By using `deleteAll` query, **your are bringing all Pujante objects new or old in the range of the delete, which is causing the issue**. One important thing to remember is that: **order of db operations are not same as your are writing in your code i.e. delete first and then insert**. I am sure if you add a delete query with certain id to delete, that will also work. One good way to verify this is `to debug the behavior`. Try it.

Comment: So there's where im failing at the first place, thinking the operations on the db will be done in the same order as they are in the code, guess i will be more careful next time. Ty :)